# Indigo on Gumstix Overo?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody installed ROS Indigo on Gumstix Overo (by installing Ubuntu 14.04)? Previously I have installed an older Ubuntu version using Linaro and then installed ROS. But I cannot find a good starting point for Ubuntu 14.04. Does anybody have a working description of how to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195384/indigo-on-gumstix-overo?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean the [source install](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM)?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-21**:
I think he's looking for instructions for installing Ubuntu 14.04 on the Gumstix, since it's required to install ROS Indigo.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-10-21**:
My apologies.  That does seem like what he means.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2014-10-21**:
Yes, instructions or a pointer to what to start with... I suppose I can always upgrade from 12.04 Linaro but it takes so much time and  suppose that there is no guarantee that the kernel works for 14.04.  But it is now unclear if we need Indigo on Gumstix Overo so I will wait until it is needed.